# sty files not found

Tags: packages

I'm new to latex, I had recently installed TexLive2016 on CentOS 7. Now, when I try to compile my `main.tex` file I get several errors:

```
biblatex.sty file not found
acronym.sty file not found
```

and so on...

Where should I run `texhash`?

Another question: It is possible that I have two different LaTeX? So that the path is set to the older latex and not to the one I installed. How can I check that? How can I correct it?

Comment: Welcome! You should not need to run `texhash`. Yes, it is possible. Yes, that is also possible. `which pdflatex` will tell you where the binary is. If it is something like `/usr/bin/...` then you are probably using CentOS packages. If it is something like `/usr/local/texlive/...` then you are probably using upstream's. You don't say *how* you installed TeX Live, so I don't know which you are trying to use. If you have both distro and upstream packages, remove whichever distribution you don't want, install a dummy package if needed, set your `PATH` correctly.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=2|0.0000 for details although obviously you'll need to adapt the instructions for your Linux distro.

Comment: You can easily have more than one latex installation. A common method to see the edition is to run `which latex` in a terminal. You also run texhash in a terminal.